# Do we want community promotion ads?

Tags: discussion, meta, advertising

Community promotion ads are ads that promote other SE sites, external web sites, or proposed Stack Exchange sites that are currently in Area 51.

As an example, [here's](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/community-promotion-ads-2015) the ads either used or proposed for Skeptics SE.

I'd like to promote some proposed Stack Exchange sites, and I assume there are various useful internet resources that could do with some advertising.

The [procedure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248216/38765) for getting community promotion ads is basically the SE deciding it wants such ads, which is what this question is about.

Comment: Community promotion ads are for graduated sites only (I think). Although we've been promised graduation we have no idea how soon we will have our own site, so it might be better to ask this question when it becomes relevant.

Comment: [posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites/248216?__=565310030#comment816265_248216) by [shog9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9): *"There's no technical restriction, but in practice a site would need an extremely pressing+unusual need for such ads in order for us to enable them on a beta site - AFAIK, we've only done this once or twice, and only temporarily."*